# запрос на поиск данных

Tags: sql

Звонит клиент и есть определенная база с телефонами, допустим это один столбец с номерами. Если номер абонента есть в базе - запрос выдает '1', если нет - '0'.

UPD. Тема закрыта, решение есть. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать count(*), но он выдает и больше 0 и насколько знаю очень тяжелая операция для БД.

Comment: Уточните, заодно, о какой именно СУБД идет речь.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE phone='+79991112233' LIMIT 1 и смотреть число возвращенных строк. Может, сюда можно сразу count() пристроить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо большое)
Ваш комментарий просто осенил меня сейчас)

Comment: @КостяВойна дык очеивдно же :-) Попробуйте мою конструкцию с count, наверное будет то что нужно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов и ... получаем еще один заминусованный вопрос с ответом в комментах

Comment: @КостяВойна если вы нашли решение - запостите его как ответ. "UPD. Тема закрыта, решение есть. Всем спасибо." - абсолютно бесполезно для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE phone='+79991112233' LIMIT 1` и смотреть число возвращенных строк. Можно еще с `COUNT` объединить, я думаю.

Answer (score 5):

В SQL-92 описана функция CASE, соответственно, она должна поддерживаться в распространённых СУБД.

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1 WHERE phone = '...') IS NULL THEN 0
       ELSE 1
```

Форма у неё, конечно, неочевидная: dura SQL sed SQL. Вместо оператора `COUNT` используется `MAX` который потенциально быстрее, поскольку не требует сканирования индекса. При отсутствующей записи `MAX(id)` должен вернуть `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `MAX(id)`, имхо, лучше бы использовать `EXISTS`, поскольку для этого случая в движке СУБД могут быть предусмотрены специальные оптимизации.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE phone = '...') THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
    END
```